# Access App content [non-root] [non-debugable] [no-backup support]

Tags: 9.0-pie, app-data

**Background:**

I am using an app (developed by my network carrier); each month a bill is generated for my usage detail, it is a PDF file, which is only visible in app (no save, no export option). In app, there is a limitation of viewing only last three-month’s bill. I want to save generated bill to maintain history.

**Scenario:**

The OS of my device is android 9, non-rooted (and I do not want to root my device).

**Analysis:**

- With some emulation, I figured-out that, app is saving these files (bills) in a (temporary) folder, which is located in `/data/data/com.app.package/files/`
- I have also tried ADB commands e.g. `run-as` and `adb backup` but not achieve the task (application is not debugable and backup support is disabled on this app).
- I also tried multi-droid app “Parallel Space” (as described in different tutorials e.g. [How to View/Edit AppData on Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPngUl1TU9I)) but shockingly, app folder (among other apps) is not accessible (might be due to some security patches).

**Question:**

Is it possible to access / copy (protected) files generated by app in `/data/data/com.app.package/files/`?

Comment: All apps store their data in `/data/data/`. That's how Android's security model works. // Even if you are able to extract data (by rooting or other means), there are chances that the data would be encrypted/scrambled in some way, leaving it not meaningful to others (except the app itself). That's how apps secure sensitive data.

Comment: @IrfanLatif as I mentioned, via emulation (Nox Android Emulator [Rooted]) on PC I have checked the data and that is as per my requirement (not encrypted).

Comment: Is the app limited to your device/the used mobile network? Because otherwise you could try to make it run in a rooted emulator on a PC, then access to the files wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Robert that would be my first option to adopt if I don't HAVE to do my all stuff on mobile.

Comment: If you have access to a PC you may try to repackage the app using `apktool` and modify the app to allow backup. Additionally you could try to find the limitation to 3 bills (if the limitation is in the app, not in the server part).

Comment: @SaadBinKhalid Just confirming that taking a screenshot(s) of your bill is disabled in carrier app or insufficient for your needs.

Comment: @Robert I have also tried 'apktool' but at 'built' step, I receive so many errors (just for information: I checked detail about errors on project's site and come to know that these are reported bug, which are not fixed yet.). Secondly, 3 bills limitation is mixture of server and app; server allow app to get bills of 3 months and app delete these bill as soon as I exit / close bill.

Comment: @MorrisonChang screenshots are not disabled but insufficient for me, as bills are consist of multiple pages (5+). Secondly, I have to extract information from these bills (text information), which is not (easily) possible if I go for this method.

Comment: @Robert , I check the method you shared but extracted `AndroidManifest.xml` file is encrypted and can't be edit. By the way I ad `d` argument in your command to de-compile apk.

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml is never encrypted. What you see is the binary xml format which can be decoded/encoded by various tools: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29669937/150978